# Remove gtm.js event action with undefined event category from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In analytics in `Behavior > Events > Top events` I see a huge number of events as follows:

```
event category: undefined
event action: gtm.js
```

This seems to be the gtm initialization event and from what I understand it should not appear in GA given that it is not a custom event.

How can I prevent this event to show up in analytics?

EDIT:
In the tagmanager preview I see:

- 7 Window Loaded
- 6 Container Loaded
- 5 DOM Ready
- 4 Container Loaded

In the `Container Loaded` the api call is `dataLayer.push({event: "gtm.js", ...})`.
In the `Container Loaded` number 4 I see the variables `_event` and `Event` set to `gtm.js` while on number 6 they are set to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your GTM.
2. Open Preview.
3. See what tag fires your gtm.js event. It likely fires on page load, on the default gtm init event.
4. Disable that tag.
5. Test/Publish the changes.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what should I do on point 3? I've updated the description with some possible usefule info

Comment: I was talking about tags firing, not the state or the value of the variables. Watch the tags firing and nothing else. First you should see it in Summary. From there, you don't even care about what event it fired on. The summary will give it the name of the tag.

Comment: In the summary I have 11 tags firing the gtm.js event, but how do I identify the problematic tag if present at all? Even if I disable them one by one how do I test if the problem is solved given that I do not know the source of the problem and in analytics I do not have real time data on the events?

Comment: ok, change the tactics then. Install the Adswerve plugin. Enable it. Now it will start showing events that you're sending to GA in your console. Go to the site and try to find your problematic event. Find how to reproduce it. It should be simple. Now in the devtools drawer, enable request blocking. Block GTM to see if that event comes from GTM or not. If it comes from GTM, then solve it with the preview. Don't forget to enable GTM. Preview shows you payloads of each tag fired. It shows you the values it sent. IF it was sent through GTM. This is a more thorough debugging process.